# Python Pyramid url replacement variable restrictions

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm developing in Pyramid 1.7 and running into an interesting scenario where some URL dispatch replacement variables match the route, while others do not.  These variables are numbers, which may not be best practice or even be allowed from what I can tell in the documentation:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html

My route is essentially defined as:

```
config.add_route("my_route", "/path/more_path/{num_var1}-{num_var2}-even_more_path")
```

The funny thing I'm seeing is that if num_var1 = 1 and num_var2 = 1, the path resolves fine.  If num_var1 = 100 and num_var_2 = 100, it also resolves fine.  Yet, if num_var1 = 1 and num_var2 = 100, it fails to resolve.  Is this a failure I should expect for some reason or should this properly resolve?

Thanks!

Comment: You neglected to mention the value of `var1`. Also do you have other routes configured? The [order in which routes are declared](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-matching) matters when matching.

Comment: Sorry I adjusted the route to be clearer.  While I had another replacement variable it was irrelevant to this question.  I do have other routes configured, but as far as I can tell I'm not getting any clashes.  Each are unique enough to steer clear of this.  You're also right that the order matters, but the oddity I'm seeing is that the replacement value itself matters.   As I mentioned, if the values are the same, I'm OK, but if I differ in the route value Pyramid errors.

Comment: Let's see the other routes. Or better yet, a full reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I made a test case which passes fine with your examples. Feel free to play with this until it reproduces your issues, but until then I'm not sure how to help.

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from webtest import TestApp

config = Configurator()
config.add_route('my_route', '/path/more_path/{num_var1}-{num_var2}-even_more_path')
config.add_view(lambda r: 'hello', route_name='my_route', renderer='string')
app = config.make_wsgi_app()
test = TestApp(app)

test.get('/path/more_path/1-1-even_more_path')
test.get('/path/more_path/100-100-even_more_path')
test.get('/path/more_path/1-100-even_more_path')
test.get('/path/more_path/1-100')  # fails, missing extra path
```